# How to get rid of slashes in JSON using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I need to query a table and then returns all the rows returned by the SQL in JSON format--

Here  is the code --

```
HashMap < String,Object > returnMap = new HashMap < String,Object > ();
Execute SQL....
def ArraySize = SQL.size();

def WhosWhoFinal = [];
for (int a = 0; a <= ArraySize - 1; a++) {
    def WhosWho = [:];
    WhosWho.put("Line ID", SQL[a]."LineID".toString().trim());
    WhosWho.put("Alpha Name", SQL[a]."AlphaName".toString().trim());
    WhosWho.put("Mailing Name", SQL[a]."MailingName".toString().trim());
    WhosWho.put("Type Code", SQL[a]."TypeCode".toString().trim());
    WhosWhoFinal << WhosWho;}
returnMap.put("WhosWho", JsonOutput.toJson(WhosWhoFinal));
return returnMap;
```

**The output that I get has slashes and is not indented--**

"WhosWho" : "[{\"Line ID\":\"0\",\"Alpha Name\":\"Alpha Name 1\",\"Mailing Name\":\"Mailing Name1\",\"Type Code\":\"\"},{\"Line ID\":\"1\",\"Alpha Name\":\"Alpha Name 2\",\"Mailing Name\":\"Mailing Name2\",\"Type Code\":\"E\"},{\"Line ID\":\"2\",\"Alpha Name\":\"Alpha Name 3\",\"Mailing Name\":\"Mailing Name3\",\"Type Code\":\"O\"}]"

**Here is what I would like to get --**

```
"WhosWho":[
   {
      "Line ID":0,
      "Alpha Name":"Alpha Name1",
      "Mailing Name":"Mailing Name1",
      "Type Code":""
   },
   {
      "Line ID":1,
      "Alpha Name":"Alpha Name2",
      "Mailing Name":"Mailing Name2",
      "Type Code":"E"
   },
   {
      "Line ID":2,
      "Alpha Name":"Alpha Name3",
      "Mailing Name":"Mailing Name3",
      "Type Code":"O"
   }
]
```

Comment: when you are talking about `output` - what do you mean? please share the code that you are using to output your `returnMap`

Answer (score 0):

You get double-quotes escaped with slashes if you serialize map object to JSON with `JsonOutput.toJson(m)` method twice. In the following line:

```
returnMap.put("WhosWho", JsonOutput.toJson(WhosWhoFinal));
```

you put a serialized JSON string under the `WhosWho` key. What you (most probably) do next (it's missing in your code example) is you call something like:

```
JsonOutput.toJson(returnMap)
```

which takes the string stored at the `WhosWho` key and serializes it to JSON string, and thus you get all double-quotes escaped.

You can avoid that by not serializing `WhosWhoFinal` to the JSON string in the first place:

```
returnMap.put("WhosWho", WhosWhoFinal);
```

Secondly, if you want to pretty-print your JSON output, you can call `JsonOutput.prettyPrint(s)` method with `s` being serialized JSON string.

```
JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(returnMap))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Szymon Stepniak.

I added this and it worked.
def jsonIn = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input); (input is the returnmap from above)

def WhosWhoList = [:];
WhosWhoList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonIn."WhosWho");